# Windows 7 x64 Professional UEFI install

Tags: uefi

How can I install Windows 7 x64 Professional on my Samsung SSD EVO 850 (500 GB) with USB or DVD?

Comment: 1. Boot Setup in UEFI mode; 2. Done. Do you have more specific issues?

Comment: Can you please add some more info.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to make a bootable USB or DVD, you can do this for Windows 7 by downloading the .iso file, and using a piece of software like [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

After that you have to boot form the USB or DVD, do this by plugging in the USB or inserting the DVD into a DVD reader. The PC should ask if you want to boot form the 'new bootable device' it found. If not, you will have to enter the BIOS, and change the boot priorities of the attached media.

Lastly, the installation will start, and the usual steps should be followed. If you don't know what options too choose etc... You can find a guide **[HERE](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-7-(Beginners))**. This guide also goes trough setting up boot priorities.